# Table does not respect margin of text

Tags: tables, overleaf

I'm developing an overleaf article using the elsevier journal template. I made a table, but the margin does not respect the margin of the text, does anyone know how to solve?

[image]

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l l l l}
\hline
\textbf{Rede Convencional} & \textbf{Rede SG}\\
\hline
Medidores eletromecânicos & Medidores inteligentes \\
Geração centralizada de energia & Geração distribuída de energia \\
Pouco monitoramento do consumidor & Monitoramento em tempo real do conusmidor \\
Rede não-automatizada & Rede automatizada \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Comparação entre rede convencional e rede SG \cite{ref10}.}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about what the table *should* look like (other than that it should inside the text block...) E.g., should the columns have equal widths?

Comment: you have specified for columns `llll` each of which has no line breaking and is as wide as the text. Your data only appears to use two columns. perhaps `p{3cm}p{3cm}`

Comment: Related/duplicate: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you (a) load the `tabularx` and `ragged2e` packages and (b) switch from a `tabular` to a `tabularx` environment. Set its overall to `\textwidth` and specify 2 (not 4) columns of type `X`. For well-spaced horizontal lines, replace `\hline` with `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` -- all macros provided by the `booktabs` package -- as appropriate.

[image]

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash%
    \hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X} % for automatic hanging indentation
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LL @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Rede Convencional} & \textbf{Rede SG}\\
\midrule
Medidores eletromecânicos & Medidores inteligentes \\
Geração centralizada de energia & Geração distribuída de energia \\
Pouco monitoramento do consumidor & Monitoramento em tempo real do conusmidor \\
Rede não-automatizada & Rede automatizada \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Comparação entre rede convencional e rede SG \cite{ref10}.}
\end{table}
```